# PHP testing multiple forms

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problem with PHP Unit testing. I'm using Laravel as framework and I'm writing tests for first time.
I have created test that should register the user, and it does, but the problem is it's returning 500 as an error (when unit testing), and I will explain why.
First this is how my register form looks like:

```
public function setRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response(['response' => false, 'message' => $validator->errors()->all()], 422);
        }

        $request['remember_token'] = Str::random(10);
        
        $user = User::create(['name' => $request->name, 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => Hash::make($request['password']), 'register_ip' => Log::getIp(), 'last_activity' => Carbon::now() ]);

        $tokenResult = $user->createToken($user->name);

        $token = $tokenResult->token;

        $tokenResult->token->save();

        UserDevices::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id, 
            'token_id' => $token->token_id, 
            'system' => Secure::getOS(), 
            'ip_address' => Secure::getIP(), 
            'browser' => Secure::browser(), 
            'device' => Secure::getDevice(), 
            'mac_address' => Secure::getMac(), 
            'full_http_client' => Secure::getUserAgent()
            ]);


        return response()
            ->json(['result' => true, 'message' => 'Register successful', 'data' => $user, 'token' => $tokenResult->accessToken ]);
    }
```

The problem is with UserDevices (or Secure class), It should take every info from the HTTP_USER_AGENT, and Secure class looks like:

```
class Secure
{
    public static function getUserAgent() {
        return  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }

    public static function getIP() {

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   
        {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
        {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
        {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))  
        {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))  
        {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        } else {
            $ip_address = 'NO IP';
        }

        return $ip_address;
    }

    public static function getOS() {

        $user_agent = self::getUserAgent();
        $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";
        $os_array       =   array(
            '/windows nt 10/i'      =>  'Windows 10',
            '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
            '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
            '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
            '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
            '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
            '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
            '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
            '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
            '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
            '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
            '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
            '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
            '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
            '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
            '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
            '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
            '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
            '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
            '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
            '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
        );

        foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) {
            if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
                $os_platform    =   $value;
            }
        }   
        return $os_platform;
    }

    public static function browser() {

        $user_agent= self::getUserAgent();

        $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";

        $browser_array  =   array(
            '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
            '/Trident/i'    =>  'Internet Explorer',
            '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
            '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
            '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
            '/edg/i'        =>  'Edge',
            '/edge/i'       =>  'Edge',
            '/opera/i'      =>  'Opera',
            '/opr/i'        =>  'Opera',
            '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
            '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
            '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
            '/ubrowser/i'   =>  'UC Browser',
            '/SamsungBrowser/i' => 'Samsung Internet',
            '/CriOS/i' => 'iPhone Chrome',
            //'/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
        );

        foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) {

            if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
                $browser    =   $value;
            }

        }

        return $browser;

    }

    public static function  getDevice(){

        $tablet_browser = 0;
        $mobile_browser = 0;

        if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
            $tablet_browser++;
        }

        if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
            $mobile_browser++;
        }

        if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
            $mobile_browser++;
        }

        $mobile_ua = strtolower(substr(self::getUserAgent(), 0, 4));
        $mobile_agents = array(
            'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
            'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
            'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
            'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
            'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
            'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
            'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
            'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
            'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

        if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
            $mobile_browser++;
        }

        if (strpos(strtolower(self::getUserAgent()),'opera mini') > 0) {
            $mobile_browser++;
                //Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
            $stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
            if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
                $tablet_browser++;
            }
        }

        if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
               // do something for tablet devices
            return 'Tablet';
        }
        else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
               // do something for mobile devices
            return 'Mobile';
        }
        else {
               // do something for everything else
            return 'Computer';
        }   
    }
    
    public static function getMac()
    {
        $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $macAddr=false;

        $arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
        $lines=explode("\n", $arp);

        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
            if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
            {
                    $macAddr=$cols[1];
            }
        }

        return $macAddr;
    }
```

I know, it's not beautiful but it's working, I will need to rewrite all of it.
So when I'm running tests on signup form, I'm receiving 500 first time, and if I run it again it will give 422, because User is already created. If I comment in UserController line for adding device or UserDevices class it will work perfectly.

The test looks like:

```
/** @test */
    public function user_register_fail_test()
    {

    $userData = [
        "name" => "John Doe",
        "email" => "doe@example.com",
        "password" => "demo12345",
        "password_confirmation" => "demo12345"
    ];

    $response = $this->withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.120 Mobile Safari/537.36'
    ])->json('POST', '/api/auth/signup', $userData);

    $response
        ->assertStatus(422)
        ->assertJson([
            'created' => true,
        ]);
    }
```

As you see I'm passing every needed Headers (I think) and it should work by my logic. Where it could be a problem? Is it headers actually? I have tested everything on postman and works fine.

Now I catched Exception for UserDevices, and it says that

> Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does your server's error log tell you about this error?

Comment: I have edited the question, it's not getting HTTP_USER_AGENT for some reason.

Comment: `HTTP_USER_AGENT` won't exist in a command-line request. You'll need to do some sort of check like you're doing for the IP.

Comment: So I can't actually set header in test like:     header('HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.120 Mobile Safari/537.36');

Comment: User Agent is a server variable, not a header. I think there may be a different place to put it